# How can I Change default Launcher with some new Launcher?

Tags: android, apk, android-source, android-launcher

I am using Android 10 in my AOSP build.
I am trying to install a downloaded launcher "Nova Launcher" in my build and I have written an Android.mk file which I am going to attach here. I am successfully able to get Nova into priv-apps but the thing is that on booting up emulator Nova is not there. The app isn't getting listed even.

The Android.mk file :

[image]

I have also listed the app into Product_packages.

Comment: Please attach the bootup logs. Packagemanager might stopped the installation due to permission issues.

Comment: Android build is successful but emulator isn't booting up properly. It is showing an error : restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading. I have updated, Updated make file : LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Lawnchair
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home Launcher2 Launcher3 Launcher3QuickStep
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT) @Magudesh